# Why is this code dying on Windows?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm trying to port some code from Linux to Windows.  I really don't know much about Windows, and so I'm kind of flying blind.  The code in question attempts to delete some directories using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

```
  // If the mergesegs worked, delete the segment dirs
    for (File file : segments.listFiles())
    {
        if (!file.equals(mergedSegFile))
        {
            LOG.debug("deleting segment dir " + file);
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file);
        }
    }
```

`segments` is a File, as is `mergedSegFile`.  It dies with an IOException `"Unable to delete file: c:\www\tomcat\crawls\test\TestingCode.site\crawldir\segments\20101128194700\parse_test\part-00000\data"`.

These files were created by a previous run of the same program (which does some Nutch crawling).  Doing an `ls -l` under cygwin shows the user and group are correct, but the perms are 000.

Further info:

- `dir` doesn't tell me anything about permissions.
- I can remove the directory with `del` on a cmd.exe window or `rm -rf` on a cygwin bash window.
- The files in question, and the directory they are in, were created earlier in the same run of the same program.
- The computer is running Windows 7, so I assume that means it's NTFS.

Comment: Maybe the program that tries to delete the directory, uses it or files in it? Extract the code which deletes the directory and make small test code, which takes the directory as a command-line argument and deletes it. Does it work?

Comment: Maybe you get more info in the StackTrace of the Exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of possibilities here. The path itself doesn't look bad. Your best bet is to try to delete that directory manually from a command prompt and see what error you get.

Things to check:

- Is the directory, or any of its contents, in use by an application?
- Is the directory, or any of its files, read-only? (Check with `dir`, not `ls`).
- Does the directory, or any of its files, have special permissions, and you are not an administrator?
- Btw, this is NTFS, I presume?

Comment: - I can remove the file just fine with "del".

Comment: - dir doesn't tell me anything about any permissions.  I assume it's NTFS - it's Windows 7.

Comment: Is "data" a file or a directory? Also, does it have any special permissions?

Comment: Permissions - look at the file with the explorer under "Properties".

Comment: THe first point "Is directory or any of its contents in use" is the most likely explanation.

Comment: The program created the file, and it should have closed it by that point.

Comment: Are you *sure* it has been closed at that point? Sounds like that's not the case.

Comment: Yeah, I think it leaked a file descriptor.